# php mongodb data model validation

Tags: php, mongodb

Perhaps I am approaching this wrong, BUT, in working with a front-end dev, who will be submitting new record data for a document in my mongodb collection, I'd like to provide a "model" which the submitted JSON data needs to validate against. For instance, I know the data needs to include a "name" and I know it needs to include an array "galleryphotos" containing individual records. And I know I need to include a "description". There are other fields they could provide, but I don't want to force them to be provided, BUT, i want to make sure that they don't submit a bunch of fields they are not supposed to be submitting, IE adding: dumfieldname: "hahaha" or whatever.

Does mongodb support a model like this? How have people done this with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

[PHP] You could create a object/class with properties and use a method to validate posted data:

```
ModelNameValidation
{
    public $name, $galleryPhotos, $description;

    public function verify($postedData)
    {
        // add verification logic heret
        // at error return false, else return true
        // e.g.
        foreach ($postedData as $key => $val) {
            if (!property_exists($this, $key)) return false;

    }
}
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php for more info on the property_exists function.

Update: remember to use escaping, validation to check input and you could use encryption here to obfuscate the key name for tight security.

Comment: that's an elegant option... let me see if this works in action :)